# shouldAutorotate / supportedInterfaceOrientations error in after iOS8.0

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode6, screen-rotation, ios8.3

my first UIViewcontroller

```
-(NSInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; }
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{ return YES; }

and through present modally segue..
```

And my Second UIViewController

```
-(NSInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; }
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{ return YES; }
```

but. my second UIviewcontroller make error SigAbrt!!!

the error message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason : [__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] attempt to insert nil object from object[0]
```

but if I remove second UIViewController that code "supportedInterfaceOrientations" this app play well...

how can i rotate some view is portrait and the other view is landscape...

my storyboard make w:any/h:any and simulated metrics:Orientation is Inferred

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint? It doesn't seem like its throwing the exception where you believe it is.

Comment: yes i add exception breakpoint maybe. this breakpoint need not?

Comment: I need to know where the app pauses on exception.

Comment: pause on exception point is main.m <thread 1. sigabrt>

Comment: Likely its something with your storyboard :/

Comment: I want to upload picture but my rep under 10.. storyboard have 2 viewcontroller and first class is landscape, second class is portrait.. between two viewcontroller.. have this problem, I think..